# Main function not working due to one method having parameters ? The method Height(int, int ) is not applicable for arguments ()

Tags: java

```
// Patrik Maco
// 18/10/21
// VERSION 1 
// Write a program that allows the user to input the length, width and height of a room (cm) - volme of balloon (m^3) prints the volume of the room in m^3 and the amount of balloons needed to fill the room.

import java.util.Scanner; 

class volume 
{      
    public static void main (String [] a)
    {     
        Run();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static int Length()
    {              
        Scanner scanner  = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Values as whole numbers- not as decimals. Do not include measurement. Good example : 5,7,9 Bad example: 3.2, 5cm");
        System.out.println("Length of room (in cm) ? ");
        length = scanner.nextInt(); 
        return length;
    } 

    public static int Width()
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Values as whole numbers- not as decimals. Do not include measurement. Good example : 5,7,9 Bad example: 3.2, 5cm");
        System.out.println("Width of room (in cm) ? ");
        int width = scanner.nextInt();
        return width;
    } 

    public static int Height(length, width)
    { 
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Values as whole numbers- not as decimals. Do not include measurement. Good example : 5,7,9 Bad example: 3.2, 5cm");
        System.out.println("Height of room (in cm) ? ");
        int height = scanner.nextInt();
        return height;
        System.out.println("Enter the volume of the baloon in M cubed");
        float volume_b;
        volume_b = scanner.nextFloat();
        float RoomVolume;
        RoomVolume = ( height * length * width);
        System.out.println("The volume of the room is : " + RoomVolume);
        float balloon3;
        balloon3 = RoomVolume/1000000;
        float BalloonAmount;
        BalloonAmount = balloon3/volume_b;
        int n;
        n = (int)BalloonAmount;
        System.out.println("The number of balloons needed is : " + n);
    }
  
    public static void Run()
    {
        int length = Length();
        int width =  Width();
        int height = Height();
    }
}
```

The method Run() returns an error

> The method Height(int, int ) is not applicable for arguments ().

I'm very new to coding and I'd like an explanation if possible as to how I can fix this issue?

Height includes two parameters in its own method, however if I input the same parameters into Run() my program doesn't run

Comment: You pass the ```length``` and ```width``` parameters to the ```Height``` method without specifying their types. You should firstly phrase the method something like ```public static int Height(int length, int width)``` then call it like Height(8, 6) for example. Or if you don't need the parameters, erase them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your method `Height`.

1. In Java, all parameters need to specify their types, so it should be declared as

```
    public static int Height(int length, int width)
```

2. all code after an unconditional return statement is unrechable

```
       return height;
       // any code after this point is unreachable
```

3. if a method takes parameters, you need to provide them explicitly:

```
    public static void Run()
    {
        int length = Length();
        int width =  Width();
        int height = Height(length, width); // you need to pass length and width!
    }
```

Other observations:

- There is no need to explicitly call `System.exit(0)` at the end of `main`, the program ends automatically at that point.
- In Java, it is a very widespread naming convention to consider fields and classes as nouns, and methods as verbs, and name them accordingly. Also, class names typically start by an uppercase letter `SomeClassName`, while method names typically start with a lower case letter `doSomething()` by convention.